# org.apache.http.httpResponce (Not a repost)

Tags: android, eclipse, apache

First of all let me tell you that im a complete noob here. I don't know about programming . But i wanted to compile this project .
With various google searches i found out that this problem is caused because of some upgradation in android sdk. 
There were about 56 errors in a project. I managed to solve 54 of them by adding several jars into the java built path. Im sure that the program itself is clean and does not contain any errors. I got it from github. Pictures of errors are provided with this thread.
Im using Eclipse mars by the way.
Errors are as follows
1.The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.http.HttpResponse. Fix the build path then try building this project
2.The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your AndroidMainifest.xml file ?, If possible share the screen srt link of problems coming in eclipse.

Comment: Where can i find AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Android SDK 23` then `HttpResponse` and other `org.apache` classes will be missing. Because, they have been removed. Instead, you could use `URLConnection` for network communication.

Comment: As i mentioned above..I have no idea about changing anything in the code. I was wondering if i could add any specific jars into the built path.And yes, Im using android sdk 23. Is it possible to download an older version of the android sdk? Thanks

Comment: For now you can use Android SDK 22. But I won't recommend it. Instead, you can follow http://www.pcsalt.com/android/recyclerview-android/ tutorial to make URLConnection.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to download sdk 22 tools. I searched but was not able to find that.
Thanks

Comment: Android SDK 22 can be downloaded from SDK manager available in Eclipse. Instead of downloading 22, you can add jar for HttpClient https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi . Still I would recommend to use URLConnection.

Comment: yeah....HttpClient is already added. But these 2 errors are still present. Beforehand there many errors and i added HttpClient-4.3.4 and it solved all other errors except these two.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use HttpClient in Android -M, Please include following jars

HttpClient : httpclient-4.0-beta2.jar 
HttpCore   : httpcore-4.1.jar

You can download these jars from here 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore

Put these jars in the libs folder of your project.

Comment: @Adithyan.C.S can you please confirm if this works for you ?